# VBA to Search Column for 1 of 3 Possible Values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with multiple columns and I am trying to search on a specific column (in this case Status) for 1 of 3 possible values (red, green, or yellow). If I was only looking for one value I think I'd be able to do a find. But since I'm looking for every instance of at least 1 of 3 values in the Status column, I'm not quite sure how that would work. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Num Status
1   Blah
2   Green
3   Red
4   Blah
5   Yellow
6   Blah
7   Blah
8   Green
9   Blah
10  Blah
11  Green
12  Green
13  Red
14  Blah
15  Green
16  Blah
17  Green
18  Blah
19  Red
20  Blah
```

Comment: Filter might be better than find if you need all of them

Comment: What are you trying to return? Or do you simply want to highlight those cells with a string you're looking for?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Hide the rest, or just find out where they are?

Comment: Apologies for leaving out some detail. If red or green or yellow is there, I want to copy the value in the cell and copy the corresponding value in the 'Number' column, and paste them into a new worksheet.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/536234/excel-how-to-vlookup-to-return-multiple-values#536254)

Answer (score 0):

This will let you specify a range to search, Start Range for the results, and a string list of the values you want to find.  It could easily be converted to an array of values to find.  If you want a case in-sensitive search you can add UCASE to both sides of the IF statement.

```
Sub TEST()
    Call MultiFindCopy(Sheet1.Range("B1:B10"), Sheet2.Range("A1"), "Red, Green, Yellow")

End Sub

Private Sub MultiFindCopy(ByRef SearchRange As Range, ByRef DestinationRange As Range, ByVal itemList As String, Optional Delimiter As String = ",")
    Dim oFindList() As String
    oFindList = Split(itemList, Delimiter)

    Dim oDestRow As Long
    Dim oSourceRow As Long

    For oSourceRow = 1 To SearchRange.Rows.Count
        For Each oItem In oFindList
            If SearchRange.Cells(oSourceRow, 1).Value = Trim(oItem) Then
                DestinationRange.Offset(oDestRow, 0).Value = SearchRange.Cells(oSourceRow, 0).Value
                DestinationRange.Offset(oDestRow, 1).Value = SearchRange.Cells(oSourceRow, 1).Value
                oDestRow = oDestRow + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I probably wasn't as descriptive as I should have been. The sheet that I need to search within is dynamic in that it changes every week, so it's never the same file. I guess I could create a reference for the most recent file and pass the reference into the MultiFindCopy function?

Comment: Yes, The procedure takes in Search Range as a parameter (as well as the destination).  You will just need a method to pass the right search range into the function.